# Fragment shader fmod, why is this not repeating

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, modulo, hlsl

I created the following fragment shader that creates a tile grid of size `_Size` using the `frac`function and draws a small seperator line in between each tile, I save the ID of the tile in its `uv.z` value so I can later adres the tile based on its id (`uv.z`).

`_Size` and `_CurrentID` can be adjusted through the inspector

```
Shader "Unlit/Fractals"
{
    Properties
    {
        [HideInInspector] _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Size ("Size", float) = 5
        _CurrentID ("ID", float) = 0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Size;
            float _CurrentID;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                _CurrentID = floor(_CurrentID);
                //Create a tile grid that is of _Size * _Size (5 in example), and create an ID for it in the .z value based on its grid position
                float3 uv = float3(frac(i.uv * _Size), (floor(i.uv.y * _Size) * _Size) + (floor(i.uv.x * _Size)));

                //Create lines to seperate the tiles
                float4 col = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
                if ((uv.x > 0.98 && uv.x < 1) || (uv.y > .98 && uv.y < 1)) 
                {
                    col *= float4(uv.x, uv.y, 0, 1);           
                }
                else
                {
                    col = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }

                //Loop through all the tiles based on the ID
                if (uv.z == fmod(_CurrentID, ((_Size) * (_Size)))) 
                {
                    col = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
                }

                //This correctly goes through every grid tile once, confirming that uv grid ID 5 corresponds to grid position (0,1)
                /*if (uv.z == _CurrentID)
                {
                    col = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
                }*/

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

(note that the grid starts at (0,0) bottom left to (5,5) top right)

To ascertain that my ID's are set up correct I looped through each `uv.z` value with the floor of the `_CurrentID` set from the inspector, which lights up every tile once, when going from 0 to 24 (inclusive) as expected.

```
if (uv.z == _CurrentID)
{
    col = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

[image: _CurrentID 7 lights up the 8th tile as expected]
example of `_CurrentID = 7` lighting up the 8th tile as expected

Now just using the `_CurrentID` would mean I can only go through every tile once. To make this repeatable regardless of how big `_CurrentID` is I should be able to use `fmod` (modulo) (although the same happens using the % modulo operator) on the `_CurrentID` so it loops back to 0 when `CurrnetID = 25`. Which I (try to) do using the following piece of code:

```
if (uv.z == fmod(_CurrentID, ((_Size) * (_Size))))
{
    col = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

This goes well for the first row (when `_CurrentId` >= 0 && < 5). However once I hit `_CurrentID = 5` things start to break, as no tile will light up, despite previously being able to confirm that `_CurrentID = 5` will light up the tile at grid (0, 1). When I set `_CurrentID  = 6` the proper tile starts lighting up again (grid pos (1,1)) which continues where grid (0, n) won't ever light up where n is greater than 0.

[image: fmod = 5 won't light up the proper square]
Example of `_CurrentID = 5` using fmod.

Things start breaking even more once my `CurrentID` goes higher than 25, where it doesn't seem to modulo loop around at all. [As seen in this gyazo gif](https://gyazo.com/74b15e6eac4741e36af9918e2dcc1497). It just seems to light up random tiles.

Starting to doubt myself I double checked the modulo maths on [WolframpAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mod%285%2C%2025%29%2C%20mod%286%2C25%29%2C%20mod%2810%2C%2025%29%2C%20mod%2825%2C%2025%29%2C%20mod%2830%2C25%29), which seems correct.

I can "solve" the issue where it skips the first tile of every row by doing `fmod(_CurrentID, ((_Size + 1) * (_Size + 1)))`, which will loop correctly through each tile on the first run (including the (0,n) tiles), but now my modulo starts looping at 36, after which it will still light up a random tile as shown in the gif.

What am I doing wrong here?

(Unity version 2020.1.1f1, same behavior confirmed in 2019.3.13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a floating point precision issue since you are comparing floats for equality.
Instead of doing that you could write something like:

```
float id = _CurrentID % (_Size*_Size);
float epsilon = .0001f;
if (abs(uv.z - id) < epsilon)
{
    col = float4(0, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Or use ints for ids.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't think about floating point precision being an issue since I floor both the `_CurrentID` and `uv.z `, but I guess even then there is still the risk for it.